# Multiple PHP webpages in one

Tags: javascript, php

So I am designing a Dashboard for the backend of my website. and i am using a PHP login system. once the user logs in I would like to have a PushMenu and a Div to display the pages of the links. What I would love to do is display multiple PHP webpages on one page. and break them up using anchors/IDs so when the user clicks on the link in the menu it will auto scroll to the anchor/ID.

So My questions is.... Is there anyway to display multiple php webpages in one page without using a frame of some sort?

Answer (score 0):

You can include a PHP page inside other PHP just using the below command. I used to provide a unique navigation bar in multiple other PHP pages.

```
<?php
    include_once('navbar.php');
?>
```